# CSS rules not working when parent is id

Tags: css, less

in the following code when I use an `id` property as a parent the `margin-bottom` does not get applied, while when I use it as a parent `class` it works, is it a case of overriding or priority thing?

**`margin-bottom: 10px` is working when parent is used as `class`:**

```
.prof {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  .parent & {
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    position: relative;
  }

.js-prof,
.js-prof-layout {
  .prof {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

**`margin-bottom: 10px` is not working with parent as `id`:**

```
.prof {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  #parent & {
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    position: relative;
  }

.js-prof,
.js-prof-layout {
  .prof {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Please note that it is the exact same page but the only difference is adding parent as `id` is not working while adding it as a `class` works! any explanation? Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to demo this.

Comment: Your CSS rules are working as intended - they aren't broken.  You should read about [CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: We need to see your HTML that uses these classes as well, otherwise we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the missing `}` was just a typo, it is indeed a matter of specificity as you thought.

The relevant parts of the translated CSS look as follows

```
.parent .prof {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
.js-prof-layout .prof {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

where you can see that the top rule for the `prof` element has two classes for a selector, while the bottom rule also has two classes. So the bottom rule has the same specificity, therefore overriding the top rule (as it appears later in the stylesheet).

However, if you replace the `.parent` with `#parent`, the top rule has an id and a class, giving it a higher specificity, so the bottom rule won't override it.

One possible solution would be to not assign a `margin-bottom` in the top rule, i.e. write only the `margin-top` rather than the `margin` shorthand.
Or write a new style rule after with a more complete selector, such as `#parent .js-prof-layout .prof`. (This one depends on the structure of the HTML though.)